# Using filter_input() causes PHP to not echo

Tags: php

I tried using filter_input() and for some reason, it does not echo anything to the browser when I use it.

```
if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tag')) && !empty(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tag')))
{
    $tag = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tag');
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Nope';
}
```

But when I use $_POST, it echos Nope. Like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '')
```

I tried to find solutions online but it seems like I am the only one with this problem.

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks.

Oh and btw, it should always echo "Nope" since I did not send any Post request.

Comment: `filter_input()` _"Gets a specific external variable by name and optionally filters it"_. Where is the `echo` statement in the top part of the `if` block? `filter_input()` doesn't echo it for you...

Comment: You cannot use isset on the result of a function call. Your code should output error unless the error output is disabled.

Comment: Just use `if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tag'))` - Had you error reporting on, would have thrown `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in...` caused by your 1st line of code.

Comment: u should really cache that function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your script is not displaying errors so you couldn't debug it.

Add this at the beginning of your script:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Your code should look like that:

```
if ($tag = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tag'))
{
    // your code
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Nope';
}
```